# TensorFlow batch tensors with different shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am studying Neural Network and I have encountered what is probably a silly problem which I can't figure out. For my first ever network, I have to create a flower image classifier in Keras and TensorFlow using the [oxford_flowers102](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/oxford_flowers102) and the MobileNet pre-trained model from TensorFlow Hub.

The issue seems to be that the images are not re-sized to (224,224,3), but they keep their original shapes which are different from one and other. However, according to my class material, my re-sizing code is correct so I don't understand what is going on and what I am doing wrong.

Thank you very much for all your help.

```
# LOADING 
dataset, dataset_info = tfds.load('oxford_flowers102', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)
training_set, testing_set, validation_set = dataset['train'], dataset['test'],dataset['validation']

# PROCESSING AND BATCHES 
def normalize(img, lbl):
        img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)
        img = tf.image.resize(img, size=(224,224))
        img /= 255
        return img, lbl
    
batch_size = 64
                                                
training_batches = training_set.cache().shuffle(train_examples//4).batch(batch_size).map(normalize).prefetch(1)

validation_batches = validation_set.cache().batch(batch_size).map(normalize).prefetch(1)

testing_batches = testing_set.cache().batch(batch_size).map(normalize).prefetch(1)

# BUILDING THE NETWORK
URL = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4"

mobile_net = hub.KerasLayer(URL, input_shape=(224, 224,3))
mobile_net.trainable = False

skynet = tf.keras.Sequential([
         mobile_net,
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
         tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation= 'softmax')
    ])

# TRAINING THE NETWORK
skynet.compile(optimizer='adam', loss= 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)

Epochss = 25

history = skynet.fit(training_batches,
                     epochs= Epochss,
                     validation_data=validation_set,
                     callbacks=[early_stopping])



ERROR:
InvalidArgumentError:  Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0. First element had shape [590,501,3] and element 1 had shape [500,752,3].
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_18246]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in your input pipeline you were batching your dataset before you were making your images of equal size. You're `def normalize(img, lbl)` is only made to handle a single image and not a complete batch.

So in order to make your code run, you will have to make the following changes, you will have to call the `map` API before `batch` API as shown below.

```
batch_size = 64

training_batches = training_set.cache().map(normalize).batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)

validation_batches = validation_set.cache().map(normalize).batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)

testing_batches = testing_set.cache().map(normalize).batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
```